# Nginx is not reachable from my Amazon Instance

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have this configuration on my `EC2 instance`
[image]

and the `status` of my `Nginx`

```
# sudo systemctl status  nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-11-03 00:45:01 UTC; 2min 33s ago
  Process: 1612 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1622 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1618 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1625 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 1.9M
      CPU: 17ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─1625 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           └─1626 nginx: worker process
```

But, each time I try to reach my server using the `IP`, I get a `TimeOut`, but if I try to reach it inside of the same server, the page exist.

Whole the configuration, a `Node.js` server running over `Nginx`. Running on an `Amazon EC2 instance`.
Today, we renew the certificates, and now the site isn't reachable.

Someone has idea about how to solve it?

Comment: Nginx running on EC2 ? You hit your Nginx IP and you get a timeout ? How is your nginx config looking like